# XNA Can't find sprite file

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I am trying to load a sprite image file (xnb) and it just cannot find the file. I have tried setting a custom root directory, I have tried just putting the file in the content and it still cant find it. This is my code.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace screen_switch
{
   
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {

        // graphics
        public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


        //page
        public PageManager PageMgr = new PageManager();
        public PageGame pageGame = new PageGame();
        public PageGame2 pageGame2 = new PageGame2();
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            //init pages
            PageMgr.Add(pageGame, this);
            PageMgr.Add(pageGame2, this);


            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            this.IsMouseVisible = true;
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            


            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            PageMgr.Update(gameTime, this);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            KeyboardState kS = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard.GetState();
            if (kS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                PageMgr.Set(pageGame2, this);
            }
            if (kS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                PageMgr.Set(pageGame, this);
            }
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            PageMgr.Draw(this);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            Texture2D squareTexture;
            squareTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("square");
            spriteBatch.Draw(squareTexture,new  Vector2(100,100), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand. The error message is:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Error loading "square". File not found.
  Source=Microsoft.Xna.Framework
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.OpenStream(String assetName)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T](String assetName, Action`1 recordDisposableObject)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String assetName)
   at screen_switch.Game1.Draw(GameTime gameTime) in C:\Users\Bigweld\source\repos\screen switch\screen switch\screen_switch\Game1.cs:line 88
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DrawFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.HostIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameHost.OnIdle()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.RunOneFrame()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.ApplicationIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.WindowsGameHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
   at screen_switch.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Bigweld\source\repos\screen switch\screen switch\screen_switch\Program.cs:line 15

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Error loading "Content\square.xnb". File not found.
```

The end goal is to load my square sprite, and paint it SOMEWHERE on the screen. I don't even care where I just need the ability to know I can place a sprite in this damn framework. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using XNA at all? XNA reached end of life nearly a decade ago.

Comment: I see no shame in using XNA as long as it's one's preference, though I'd recommend using Monogame, as that has the same framework as XNA, but remains up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The `squareTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("square");` should be defined in the `LoadContent()` method.

And make sure your sprite is found in the contents folder in your Solution Explorer. And that the naming/directory is correct.